# Why is typecasting necessary when checking types in loops?

Tags: swift, loops, class, typecasting-operator

I'm trying to more deeply understand typecasting, and don't understand why it's necessary in this example:

```
class Animal { }
class Fish: Animal { }

class Dog: Animal {
    func makeNoise() {
        print("Woof!")
    }
}

let pets = [Fish(), Dog(), Fish(), Dog()]
```

I'm reading that to check the type in the above array, I need to run the following code:

```
for pet in pets {
    if let dog = pet as? Dog {
        dog.makeNoise()
    }
}
```

And that the following code would crash:

```
for pet in pets {
    if pet == Dog() {
        pet.makeNoise()
    }
}
```

It returns the following error:

```
error: Learn Swift.playground:24:13: error: value of type 'Animal' has no member 'makeNoise'
        pet.makeNoise()
        ~~~ ^~~~~~~~~
```

Why is that? Wouldn't that last block of code just check if the item in the array is Dog()?

Currently, my guess is that I don't fully understand the implicit type of "pet" in the for loop. I've assumed that it just guesses the type based on the type of items in the array, which in our case is an Object.

Comment: Not really related to your question on casting but you can also write your loop as `for case let pet as Dog in pets { ... }` and you won't have to do any casting inside the loop

Comment: @dan that seems much cleaner. Is there any downside? I wouldn't imagine so, but I'm curious if you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this line

```
print(type(of: pets))
```

it displays `Array<Animal>`. The base class is the common denominator of the items in the array.

In your second example you should get another compiler error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Animal' and 'Dog'

Nevertheless without a type cast `pet` remains `Animal` and *'Animal' has no member 'makeNoise'*

Comment: So the fundamental error is that you can't use the comparison '==' operator on classes, is that right? Do you know why that is?

Comment: Yes, the usual way is the `is` operator e.g. `if pet is Dog` but this doesn't cast the type either.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of the array `pets`: It should be `[Animal]`/. Animals cannot make noise, so you need to explicitly check if its a Dog.  Essentially you have lost the type of `Dog` by boxing it inside of a heterogeneous array with other `Animals`.  It doesn't make sense to call `makeNoise()` on an Animal, so the compiler forces you to check that the element of the array actually is a `Dog` before you call `makeNoise()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `is` keyboard when checking the type of an instance. e.g. `if pet is Dog { ... }`, you are currently just initialising a new object of it redundantly.

So then, when you are asking `if pet is Dog { ... }`, you are just retrieving a boolean value based on that statement, but it doesn't make the compiler refer to `pet` as `Dog`.
On the contrary, when you say `if let dog = pet as? Dog { ... }`, you are creating a new value of type `Dog?`, which makes the compiler refer to it as a `Dog`.